# Unable to Infalte Custom Dialog in Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, layout-inflater, customdialog

I have a Tabbed Activity, In Tab2.Java,
I want to show a Custom Dialog on a Button Click. (For Custom Dialog, I have a separate xml file named: *dg_selct.xml*.)
Code:

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {

    Button btn;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);


        btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                View bView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dg_selct,null);

                dialog.setView(bView);
                AlertDialog customDialog = dialog.create();
                customDialog.setTitle("Search");
                customDialog.show();

            }
        });
```

Here is **dg_selct.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkpg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/clspg"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"

            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:text="Mark the Groups, You want to Send the Message:"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chknur"
            android:checked="true"

            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chkpg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chkpg"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="@string/clsn" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkprep"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chknur"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chknur"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/clsp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkone"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chkprep"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chkprep"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="@string/cls1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/chktwo"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chkone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chkone"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/cls2" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkthree"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chktwo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chktwo"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:text="@string/cls3" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkfour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chkthree"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chkthree"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/cls4"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkfive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/chknur"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/cls5"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chksix"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chkfive"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chknur"
            android:text="@string/cls6" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chksvn"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chksix"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chkprep"
            android:text="@string/cls7" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chknine"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chksvn"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chkone"
            android:text="@string/cls9" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkten"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chknine"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chktwo"
            android:text="@string/cls10" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkextra"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/chkten"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chkthree"
            android:text="@string/clsextra"
            android:textSize="23sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also, When I use `final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tab2.this);` instead of `final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());` , Compiler gives an error: **"Builder (android.Content.context) in Builder cannot be applied to com.abc.Tab2"**

***dg_select.xml* has some CheckBoxes and a TextView. But When Dialog is shown, I only see the title as mentioned in above Code.
How do I inflate the dg_selct.xml in this Dialog?**

Comment: share Your   custom layout **dg_selct** with question

Comment: did you try to change your `AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());` to `AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());`?

Comment: tried both: `getContext()` and `getActivity()`
No Sucess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this use **`Dialog`** instead of **`AlertDialog`**

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());  
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dg_selct);

// to bind your control  from dialog like this
final  TextView textView= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.YourTextBiew);

final  CheckBox checkBox= (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.YourCheckBox);

final Button btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);

textView.setText("PREM");
dialog.setTitle("Search");
dialog.show();
```

**UPDATE**

> change Your **`RelativeLayout`** hight & width to **`match_parent`** OR **`wrap_content`** like below code

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: Still Same, Only Title is shown 
And: object of textView says "It is never used"

Comment: share your custom layout for dialog and check updated ans @ZubairYounas

Comment: Layout file has been shared.
And setText is now being used, But not shown in Dialog.
Dialog still consists of Title only

Comment: post Screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Here ,I saw your xml of dg_select.xml  in which you set the height and width of RelativeLayout is 0dp That's why it is unable to show your checkbox. You must have to set **RelativeLayout** height or width **wrap_content** or **match_parent**.

**AlertDialog** is the part of an **Activity** that's why it is unable to take reference of fragment.So, You initializing the AlertDialog you must you the Activity reference.

Comment: Yes. That was the Problem.
Don't know why compiler itslef set the height and with to 0 :/

Comment: When we use weightsum and weight  that we needs to set the height or width 0dp